# How to resolve error For the response: use 'Content-Type' header"

Tags: rest, design-patterns, format, mulesoft

I'm using Design Center to specify my API and have to add some Rule Sets.
One on them is API Team Best Practices and indicates the follow error:

> Error: [API Team Best Practices] For the response use 'content-Type' header.

My code follow like this:

[image: Design Center Image]

Then I Add the content Header, like this

[image: After fix the error]

But The Rule set still error me , calling the following message:

> Parameters of type string must have the format field declared.

What am I missing? Any help?

Use this article as reference of my problem
https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/Error-Error-Anypoint-Best-Practices-For-the-response-use-Content-Type-header-occurs-wen-designing-an-API-Specs-in-Design-Center-based-on-Anypoint-API-governance-Best-Practices

Comment: Please don't use images for text content in Stackoverflow and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should remove all the facets that you don't need to use explicitly. The article that you linked only used description. The example that Also you are using incorrectly content-type. Its value should be MIME types, not an HTTP response status. Maybe you copied it from another place.